# How to exclude a particular kind of control from a foreach loop?

Tags: c#

I am attempting to validate a forms controls to see if they are empty and found an interesting point in my flailing.

```
List<string> emptycontrols = new List<string>();

foreach (Control control in Mainform.V_Datafield.Controls)
{
    if (control.Text.Contains(null))
    {
        emptycontrols.Add(control.Name);
    }
}
if (emptycontrols.Count > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Empty fields detected:", emptycontrols.ToString()); 
}
```

Above is my mediocre solution and when run it comes up that a control, namely the `DateTimePicker` control can never be empty and quite rightly so.

Ultimately my question is how would I exclude the `DateTimePicker` control from the `foreach` loop so that it will ignore it but continue to check the other controls?

The groupbox (`V_datafield`) contains:

- 10 x TextBoxes
- 1 x RichTextBox
- 1 x DateTimePicker as mentioned above.

Comment: `control.Text.Contains(null)` looks odd. You probably wanted to write `string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text)`. Besides that, loop over `Mainform.V_Datafield.Controls.Where(c => !(c is DateTimePicker))`

Comment: You know that does actually seem to make a lot more sense now that I've seen it, Let's just go and change that real quick

Comment: I'd prefer the LINQ solution (using Where) over a type check inside the loop.

Comment: @Clemens By all means I could switch the accepted answer if that makes more sense, may I ask why the LINQ solution is more preferable?

Comment: Less code. No old fashioned continue statement. IMO better readable.

Comment: That makes sense, will adjust the selected answer accordingly

Comment: And the other answer also shows how to avoid the whole loop. Adding `.ToList()` at the end of the LINQ statement would execute it and make it return a `List<string>`, which you originally had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `is` like this:

```
foreach (Control control in Mainform.V_Datafield.Controls)
    if (!(control is DateTimePicker) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
        emptycontrols.Add(control.Name);
```

Or, actually, your loop could be removed using LINQ to become:

```
var emptyControls = Mainform.V_Datafield.Controls
    .Cast<Control>()
    .Where(control => !(control is DateTimePicker))
    .Where(control => string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
    .Select(control => control.Name);
```

using two `Where` to keep the logic from the previous code but they could be merged using `&&`.

Comment: Not sure if `IsNullOrEmpty` was intended. `Text == null` may as well be appropriate.

Comment: Just used `IsNullOrEmpty` as OP seemed to like your proposition in the question's comments

Comment: Please excuse my dumbness but:
`'Control.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'Control.ControlCollection'`

Comment: @JMC sorry! I assumed it implemented `IEnnumerable<Control>`, I'll fix my answer.

Comment: @Halex Not a problem at all! I appreciate the quick response (And you putting up with me) working perfectly now :D

Answer (score 5):

You can always check like following inside your `foreach` loop

```
if (control is DateTimePicker)
     continue;
```